How to create an "enumerable" decorator for accessor methods in TypeScript
I'm trying to make an @enumerable decorator that will expose properties defined via accessor methods.
A function to do this on instances of the class is fairly trivial:
// This works great when called in the class constructor like ```makeEnumerable(this, ['prop1', 'prop2'])```
const makeEnumerable = (what: any, props: string[]) => {
  for (const property of props) {
    const descriptor = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(what.constructor.prototype, property);
    if (descriptor) {
      const modifiedDescriptor = Object.assign(descriptor, { enumerable: true });
      Object.defineProperty(what, property, modifiedDescriptor);
    }
  }
};

However, it does not seem possible to turn this into a decorator, because it doesn't have the instance.
// Does not work for Object.keys, Object.getOwnPropertyNames or Object.entries
function enumerable (value: boolean = true): any {
  return function (target: any, propertyKey: string, descriptor: PropertyDescriptor): any {
    if (descriptor) {
      Object.assign(descriptor, { enumerable: value });
    }
  };
}

The property does still enumerate in for (const x in y) structures (strangely), but nowhere else  - and worse, Object.entries throws an error.
Here is an example using the functions above:
class MyClass {
  #privateVal1: any;
  #privateVal2: any;

  constructor () {
    makeEnumerable(this, ['b']);
  }

  @enumerable(true)
  get a () {
    return this.#privateVal1;
  }

  set a (val: any) {
    this.#privateVal1 = val;
  }

  get b () {
    return this.#privateVal2;
  }

  set b (val: any) {
    this.#privateVal2 = val;
  }
}

const enumerableA = new MyClass();
enumerableA.a = 5;
enumerableA.b = 6;

const keys = [];
for (const key in enumerableA) {
  keys.push(key);
}

console.log({
  'forin': keys, // ['a', 'b']
  'keys': Object.keys(enumerableA), // ['b']
  'keys(proto)': Object.keys(Object.getPrototypeOf(enumerableA)), // ['a']
  'getOwnPropertyNames': Object.getOwnPropertyNames(enumerableA), // ['b']
  'getOwnPropertyNames(proto)': Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Object.getPrototypeOf(enumerableA)), // ['constructor', 'a', 'b']
});

console.log({
  'entries': Object.entries(enumerableA), // Error('Cannot read private member #privateVal1 from an object whose class did not declare it');
  'entries(proto)': Object.entries(Object.getPrototypeOf(enumerableA)), // Error('Cannot read private member #privateVal1 from an object whose class did not declare it');
});

Is there any way to use a decorator to make an accessor method an enumerable property?

Which decorators are you trying to use? the new ones or the old experimental ones?

@Harry Mustoe-Playfair Is there any error you see?

(see prev comment about which decorators you're using) Note that enumerability isn't the only thing going on, there's also ownership/inheritance. It's not strange that for (const k in o) will enumerate more things than Object.keys(o) does, because the former will give you all enumerable keys, whereas the latter only gives you own enumerable keys. The whole problem you're having is that getters are really prototype properties, not instance properties. You can certainly make those getters enumerable, but you want them to be own also, which is a different thing altogether.

so if the previous comment makes sense, you might want to [edit] to remove the "strangely" part, and specify that you're trying to make accessor methods both enumerable and own. This might turn out not to be possible with decorators, but at least the question would be more focused.

Prototype vs Instance properties
There's nothing strange in that, you'll have to understand Prototype vs Instance properties

makeEnumerable sets enumerable descriptors on the instance.
enumerable decorator modifies prototype-level descriptors.

You are expecting Object.keys(enumerableA) to be ['a', 'b'], like 'forin': keys, but:

The for...in loop iterates over both own and inherited enumerable properties.
While, Object.keys returns only it's own enumerable properties.



Check this MDN blog for more info. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Enumerability_and_ownership_of_properties#querying_object_properties
Explaination of the Outputs
for (const key in enumerableA)

Output: ['a', 'b']
Why:

The for...in loop iterates over both own and inherited enumerable properties.
b and a are enumerable but on different level. b is made enumerable by makeEnumerable as instance property and a prototype property made enumerable by the @enumerable decorator.




Object.keys(enumerableA)

Output: ['b']
Why:

Object.keys lists only the own enumerable properties.
b is made an own enumerable property by makeEnumerable function in constructor.
a is still on the prototype, so it is excluded.




Object.keys(Object.getPrototypeOf(enumerableA))

Output: ['a']
Why:

It lists only enumerable properties on the prototype, @enumerable decorator modifies the prototype-level descriptor for a.
b is non-enumerable on prototype because makeEnumerable function made enumerable on instance only.




Object.getOwnPropertyNames(enumerableA)

Output: ['b']
Why:

It lists all own properties (both enumerable and non-enumerable) but ignores prototype properties.
b is an own property on the instance.




Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Object.getPrototypeOf(enumerableA))

Output: ['constructor', 'a', 'b']
Why:

This lists all own properties (both enumerable and non-enumerable) defined directly on the prototype.
constructor, and b are non-enumerable but exist on prototype.



Why Object.entries throws an error
Object.entries access all the enumerable own properties.

When querying Object.entries(enumerableA):

It access b as it is enumerable property on instance. While accessing b, the this context of get b() {...} is the instance  MyClass { b: [Getter/Setter] }.
So it works fine, because the private properties in the class are accessible when this referes to the instance.


But when querying Object.entries(Object.getPrototypeOf(enumerableA))

It accesses a because a is an enumerable property on the prototype.
But it throws an error because the this context for the get a(){...} is the prototype object ({ a: [Getter/Setter] }), not an instance of MyClass



You must understand how private properties are handled by typescript.

Typescript generate some functions to check this when a method is called. If this is not same as own class it throws an error.
Check compiled Javascript code for more details.

Is there any way to use a decorator to make an accessor method an enumerable property?
No, it is not possible to make instance properties enumerable directly using decorators in Typescript because property decorators in Typescript only have access to the class prototype for instance members, not the instance itself.

A property decorator in Typescript is executed before any instances of the class are created. It operates at the class definition level.
If you want to make instance properities enumerable use makeEnumerable function, as you used for b.




I hope, I've addressed all your issues. If anything else you'd like to clarify, feel free to ask. Happy learning!

Extremely comprehensive answer! Thank you...
So there is no way of looping over just own and inherited enumerable properties of an object!? That seems crazy!

There's an only way you can loop through own and inherited enumerable properties is using for...in loop. Check that MDN link (mentioned in answer) you will know everything you are asking for.
